# Initialise unique_ptr in the unit tests

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
class foo {

    public:
        foo();
        void setMean(std::shared_ptr<std::valarray<double>> input);
    private:

        std::shared_ptr<std::valarray<double>> mean;

}
```

The `.cpp` file:

```
foo::foo() : mean(nullptr) {
}

void foo::setMean(std::shared_ptr<std::valarray<double>> input){
    mean = input;
}
```

Now, in the unit test file:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::valarray<double>> input = std::make_shared<std::valarray<double>>(std::initializer_list<double>{0.0, 0.0});

std::unique_ptr<foo> meanObj;

meanObj->setMean(input);
```

The code breaks when the control goes inside `setMean` function.

**Is there a problem with the initialisation of the `unique_ptr`?**

Comment: where do you initialize `meanObj`?

Comment: there is no foo object anywhere actually

Comment: Why do you even need a `unique_ptr`? Just do `foo meanObj; meanObj.setMean(input);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last 2 lines of your example, rewritten using raw pointers, would be

```
foo* meanObj = nullptr;
meanObj->setMean(input);
```

Do you see the problem? You're dereferencing `nullptr`. You need to first create a `foo` object that the `unique_ptr` manages

```
auto meanObj(std::make_unique<foo>());
// or std::unique_ptr<foo> meanObj(new foo);
meanObj->setMean(input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason I can't use `std::make_unique`. But using the alternate approach, it works.

Comment: @chintans `make_unique` was added in C++14, so you need an stdlib implementation that supports that version.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, where are you initializing the `std::unique_ptr`?

You're not, and that's why the `std::unique_ptr` will point to `nullptr`, and you can't deference it, so you are getting a segmentation fault.

Initialize it with `std::make_unique`:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> meanObj = std::make_unique<foo>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. You need to initialise it with an actual object, like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> meanObj(std::make_unique<foo>());
```

Without this, you're invoking the default constructor of `std::unique_ptr`, which sets the pointed-to underlying member to `nullptr`. Your deference on the next line is therefore a null pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

You do not set `meanObj` to point/own anything. You need to initialize the smart pointer with a `foo` object.

In case you don't use C++14 and you don't want to initialise your `unique_ptr` in the same place you declare it, you can do

```
meanObj.reset( new foo() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer, but from what I can see you don't need to use a `unique_ptr` at all. Just use the object itself:

```
foo meanObj;
meanObj.setMean(input);
```

Comment: The code I posted is a cut down version, the actual code is way too complicated.